# Random movement using physics, CGPoint, vectors, a little confused on the physics/math side of things

Tags: objective-c, xcode, physics, vector-graphics, chipmunk

I've managed to get Chipmunk physics and some other stuff to lay down a ball on my screen, and I can affect the gravity with some buttons / accelerometer. Yay me!

Next up, I'd like to turn off the gravity, and simulate a top-down view, where that ball moves around the screen of its own volition. I can apply forces to the ball using `body -> f = cpv(dx, dy)`, but I'm not quite up on my physics and mathematics, so I'm trying to understand how the two values I feed it cause the movement.

I understand that positive values will move it right or down, and negative values will move it left or up, but that's about all I'm understanding at this point.

If I wanted to, say, pick a random compass bearing (0 - 359 degrees) and move it on that bearing, how would such a value translate into a vector?

I've created this method, but it's not working as expected and I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong:

```
- (CGPoint) getVectorFromAngle: (float) angle AndMagnitude: (float) magnitude
{
    float x = magnitude * cos(angle);
    float y = magnitude * sin(angle);
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(x, y);
    NSLog(@"Made a CGPoint of X: %f and Y: %f.", point.x, point.y);
    return point;
}
```

If I feed it an angle of `45` and a magnitude of `10`, it creates X as 5.253220 and 8.509035. However, the calculator found [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vector-calculator.html) shows that it should create X and Y as 7.0711.

What do I have wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: [Converting between polar and Cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vector-calculator.html

The converter here works and does exactly what I need, but it doesn't explain how it's doing it! Any ideas?

Comment: Well, that is basic trigonometry. `(x, y)` is a vector in cartesian coordinates, and "magnitude + angle" describe a vector in polar coordinates. The conversion is described in that Wikipedia article or any book/article on trigonometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sin and cos take angles in radians, multiply your angles by π/180.

Comment: Yes, I was just writing this myself :D

Answer (score 0):

It's also good to point out that Chipmunk already contains a functions that do exactly what you want.

```
cpvmult(cpvforangle(radians), magnitude)
```